# JQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'fr' of undefined

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to use jquery datetimepicker but I have a track when I try to use a french translation file.

My package.json file is the following:

```
"@angular/core": "^9.1.7",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.21",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
```

My angular.json file is the following:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js",
          "node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        ]
```

My datetimepicker is declare as follows:

```
const options = {
  timepicker: true,
  datepicker: true,
  format: 'd/m/Y h:i',
  hours12: false,
  step: 15,
  theme: 'dark',
};
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
  timepicker: true,
  datepicker: true,
  format: 'd/m/Y h:i',
  hours12: false,
  step: 15,
  theme: 'dark',
  onShow: function (ct) {
    this.setOptions({
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: $('#endDate').val() ? $('#endDate').val() : false,
    });
  },
});
$(function () {
  $.datetimepicker.setDefaults($.datetimepicker.regional['fr']);
});
$('#startDateToggle').on('click', function () {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker('startDateToggle');
});
```

The complete error message is as folows:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'fr' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'fr' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:4200/main.js:712:67)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:4200/scripts.js:2:30005)
    at t (http://127.0.0.1:4200/scripts.js:2:30307)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:621:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:4200/vendor.js:56900:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:620:40)
    at Zone.runTask (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:389:51)
    at invokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:702:38)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:691:52)
    at timer (http://127.0.0.1:4200/polyfills.js:2774:33) undefined
```

Comment: You could check whether it is `datepicker['fr']` or `datetimepicker['fr']`. Another idea is to change the script import order: `datepicker-fr.js` before `jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the "regional" was not created under datetimepicker.

Perhaps you can include this file (or it's content) to your component:
    https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js

See also this. [How to use jQuery Datepicker in Angular](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/angular/angular_jquery.aspx)

One question: why are you trying to use jquery. It's not a good idea to mix jquery and angular.
Perhaps you can use this one: [angular material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

Unfortunately there is no built-in datetimepicker (date & time) for angular material.
But you can have a look at [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) and [ng-pick-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime)